# Unable to build from Android Studio

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I get this error message when trying to build my project from Android Studio

> org.gradle.tooling.UnsupportedVersionException: The specified Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle' is not supported by this tooling API version (1.7, protocol version 4): The specified Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle' is not supported by this tooling API version (1.7, protocol version 4)

I can build my project from executing

```
gradlew assemble
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out if I import module by "Create module from existing sources", this problem went away.
I had selected "Import module from external model" with Gradle.  This option generated the above message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a temporary issue with the current build of AndroidStudio. I downloaded and installed gradle locally and referenced that installation for my project via File -> Settings >> Gradle >> Use Local Gradle Distribution and was able to build and install.

Alternatively, using gradlew from the Terminal window worked as well. `./gradlew tasks` show you available taslks including "installDebug".